# CefSharp in a window opened with ShowDialog doen't work

Tags: wpf, modal-dialog, cefsharp, showdialog, windowsformshost

In WPF, I use CefSharp for WinForm that runs in a WindowsFormsHost in a Window. Everything works like charm when I display the Window using Show(). But if I use ShowDialog(), CefSharp seems not to load. The WindowsFormsHost just display it's background color.

```
<WindowsFormsHost Name="xamlBrowser" Grid.Row="0" Background="#f5f2e9" />
```

```
public WindowEditor() {
    InitializeComponent();

    if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "app"), "editor.html"))) {
        ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("localfolder://cefsharp/editor.html", MainWindow.rc1); // with RequestContext for the custom scheme
        xamlBrowser.Child = browser;

        browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register(
            "boundAsync",
            new BoundEditorObject() { Reference = this },
            true
        );

        browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += OnIsBrowserInitializedChanged;
        browser.FrameLoadEnd += OnFrameLoadEnd;
    }
}
```

```
new WindowEditor() { Text = "Init text" }.ShowDialog()
```

I need to get a value back after closing the Window. 
Do you know why this isn't working using ShowDialog() ??

Thanks a lot

Comment: Vaigue recollection of looking at this scenario some years ago and deciding it wasn't possible. The message loop is handled differently when ShowDialog is called. Is there a specific reason you need to use the WinForms version over the native WPF version?

Comment: You can try integrating CEF into your apps existing message loop to see if that makes 
A difference see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#multithreadedmessageloop

Comment: The first sentence of your question is not complete Could you please edit your question ?

Comment: @amaitland It's only for performance purpose. The WPF version is laggy on the "old" computers I'm developing for

Comment: Integrate `CEF` into your apps message loop, hopefully that will resolve the issue. Past that you can download the source from GitHub and debug this yourself, see what's going on.